# What is the meaning of the term 'headless' in the context of Java development in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, headless

What is the meaning of the term 'headless' in the context of Java development in Eclipse?

Comment: Oh my, harsh are the middle-ages!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Headless` means non-gui. [Here](http://www.developertesting.com/archives/month200508/20050823-HeadlessHelloWorldInEclipse.html) is a good article.

Comment: Just to confirm I got it right, any use of Eclipse APIs in a non-GUI application is a 'headless usage of eclipse'. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
java -jar /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar -noSplash -data "workspace" -application org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild
```

It works for me

(The workspace parameter must be without "")